# Java script WebSocket onopen event not firing?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, phpwebsocket

**this my server  code is php Ratchet**

```
    <?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';



use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use App\BroadCastController;

$server = IoServer::factory(new BroadCastController(),8080);

$server->run();
```

**This BroadCastController**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class BroadCastController implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        // $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        // echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
        //     , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        // foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
        //     if ($from !== $client) {
        //         // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
        //         $client->send($msg);
        //     }
        // }

        print "\n";
        print "====================FROM=========================\n";
        print "\n";
        print_r(gettype($from));
        print "\n";
        print "====================MESSSAGE=========================\n";
        print "\n";
        print_r(gettype($msg));
        print "\n";
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo " :::::: Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

**This Client Side JavaScript**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <script>  

        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
        console.log(ws);
        ws.onopen = function() {
            console.log("open!");
        }

        ws.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log(event.data);
        }

        ws.onclose = function() {
            console.log("Closed");
        }   

        ws.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            console.log("trouble in paradise");
        } 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**connection success but onopen event not firing :(**
[image: as you see request success]

**javascript in client side is connected to server successfuly. it should run onopen event in client side**
[image: new connection is now listen to server why onopen event in client side not working !!!]

**this should fire connection is created**
[image: THIS NOT FIRING]

**as you see here is not print "open!"**
[image: it should print "open!"]

Comment: console.log ws.readyState and see if it's 1

Comment: ................................................ok

Comment: ......................................i get  0

Comment: Then the connection is a lie. Try to connect with an external tool like: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/websocket-test-client/fgponpodhbmadfljofbimhhlengambbn

Answer (score -1):

**i found the problem is my bad
i forget add this classes as prameter  in server.php code**
[image]